# Wifi Adapter not found on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS; previously it was workng fine though

Tags: wireless, internet, adapter

Output of

`ls /sys/class/net/`

is as below

```
bnep0 lo
```

&

`ifconfig` gives the output as below

```
bnep0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.44.132  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.44.255
        inet6 fe80::5be9:8396:9ad5:fec4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:ed:b9:51:18:ea  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11716  bytes 11167708 (11.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10320  bytes 1022913 (1.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 5316  bytes 422264 (422.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5316  bytes 422264 (422.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Does that mean Wireless Card is not there at all ? I've given my laptop for cleaning/dusting/servicing etc before this happened.

I'm currently using bluetooth internet from mobile, as I couldn't find a LAN cable.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Later edit:

output of

```
lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list
```

is as below

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: edited the question; thank you for the response.

Comment: Are you using a built-in PCI device or a USB dongle?

Comment: Built-in wifi adaptor only for wifi connection...I've a dongle (integrated usb receiver) for wireless mouse & keyboard, that's all.

Comment: It looks like the adapter is broken or disabled in BIOS. If it is not seen in `lspci` there is no way to do anything from the OS.

Comment: okay...got the hardware replaced...thank you!